# Getting array of arrays, need array of numbers. Ideas?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow

I've been trying to process a dataset to feed into an LSTM model.
Here is the code I've come up with to produce an array with specific timesteps forward and back for a times series dataset.

```
stepsForward = 3
stepsBack = 7
trainTestSplit = 0.75

df_item = pd.DataFrame(df.Cannonball)

minmax = MinMaxScaler().fit(df_item.values.reshape((-1,1)))
df_normalize = minmax.transform(df_item.values.reshape((-1,1)))

def walk_forward(X, stepsBack, stepsForward, trainTestSplit):
  n_records = len(X)
  split = int(n_records*trainTestSplit-stepsForward)
  x = []
  y = []
  for i in range(n_records):
    x.append(X[i : i + stepsBack])  
    y.append(X[i + stepsBack : i + stepsBack + stepsForward])
  
  xtrain = x[:split].copy()
  xtest = x[split + stepsForward : n_records - stepsForward].copy()
  ytrain = y[:split].copy()
  ytest = y[split + stepsForward : n_records - stepsForward].copy()
    
  print('train=%d, test=%d' % (len(xtrain), len(xtest))) 
  return np.asarray(xtrain), np.asarray(ytrain), np.asarray(xtest), np.asarray(ytest) 

X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = walk_forward(df_normalize, stepsBack, stepsForward, trainTestSplit)

y_train_padded = pad_sequences(np.array(y_train), maxlen= stepsBack, 
                               padding='post', dtype='float32')
y_test_padded = pad_sequences(np.array(y_test), maxlen= stepsBack, 
                               padding='post', dtype='float32')

X_train_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train, dtype = tf.float32)
X_test_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_test, dtype = tf.float32)
y_train_padded_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train_padded, dtype = tf.float32)
y_test_padded_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test_padded, dtype = tf.float32)
```

At first glance the code should produce identical arrays for X_train and X_test. After running the code the arrays I get are:
X_train[:3]

```
array([[[0.        ],
        [0.97938144],
        [0.97938144],
        [0.97938144],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608]],

       [[0.97938144],
        [0.97938144],
        [0.97938144],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608]],

       [[0.97938144],
        [0.97938144],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608],
        [0.98453608]]])
```

X_test

```
array([array([[0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289]]),
       array([[0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95360825]]),
       array([[0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95360825],
       [0.95360825]])], dtype=object)
```

Does anybody know what's going on here?

X_train has the correct format, X_test is an array of arrays instead of an array with deeper dimensions. I've tried several configurations and thought copying the datasets would fix it but no luck.

Edit:
Here is the error I am getting due to the X_test being an array of arrays when converting to a tensor.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/_asarray.py:83: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-4e51ce7906cd> in <module>()
     33 
     34 X_train_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_train, dtype = tf.float32)
---> 35 X_test_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(X_test, dtype = tf.float32)
     36 y_train_padded_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_train_padded, dtype = tf.float32)
     37 y_test_padded_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(y_test_padded, dtype = tf.float32)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
    104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
    105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
--> 106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
    107 
    108 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Edit2:
This is being ran in Google Colab.

The following code produces an X_train that's an array of arrays like X_test. Still not sure what's causing this.

```
  x_copy = np.copy(x)
  x_copy2 = np.copy(x)
  y_copy = np.copy(y)
  y_copy2 = np.copy(y)
  xtrain = x_copy[:split]
  xtest = x_copy2[split + stepsForward : n_records - stepsForward]
  ytrain = y_copy[:split]
  ytest = y_copy2[split + stepsForward : n_records - stepsForward]
```

But this code produces the X_train and X_test just as in the format I first provided.

```
  x_copy = x.copy()
  x_copy2 = x.copy()
  y_copy = y.copy()
  y_copy2 = y.copy()
  xtrain = x_copy[:split]
  xtest = x_copy2[split + stepsForward : n_records - stepsForward]
  ytrain = y_copy[:split]
  ytest = y_copy2[split + stepsForward : n_records - stepsForward]
```

Comment: Either the source arrays didn't match in size, or special steps were taken to make this object array.  Does `np.stack(X_test)` do anything useful?

Comment: np.stack(X_test,X_test) returns array([[array([[0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289],
       [0.95876289]])

Comment: Try `np.stack(X.test.ravel()`.  That is, change the outer array to 1d so `stack` can (try) to work on the individual arrays.  What you display looks like all arrays have the same shape, but I suspect the real data is different.